# Wordpress can't upload images due to permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, php, wordpress

I'm having problems trying to get Media uploads working on my VPS w/ Wordpress. My `Apache` service is running as user:group `apache:apache`. My user folder is owned by my user `eugene` and grouped `apache`. I can load my Wordpress site but I cannot get any media uploads to work. Every file/folder has `rwx` for the user and group level.

I get the error:

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I setting this up the wrong way?

```
[eugene@myvps ~]$ pwd
/home/eugene
[eugene@myvps ~]$ ll
total 0
drwxrws---. 3 eugene apache 24 Dec 11 09:58 public_html
[eugene@myvps ~]$ cd public_html/
[eugene@myvps public_html]$ ll
total 0
drwxrws---. 3 eugene apache 16 Dec 11 09:58 website.com
[eugene@myvps public_html]$ cd website.com/
[eugene@myvps website.com]$ ll
total 4
drwxrws---. 5 eugene apache 4096 Dec 11 13:53 www
[eugene@myvps website.com]$ cd www
[eugene@myvps www]$ ll
total 7100
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache     418 Sep 24  2013 index.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache 7079339 Dec 11 09:58 latest.tar.gz
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache   19930 Jan  1  2015 license.txt
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    7358 Dec  3 08:46 readme.html
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache     169 Dec 11 12:10 test.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    5035 Oct  6 14:56 wp-activate.php
drwxrws---.  9 eugene apache    4096 Dec 11 11:51 wp-admin
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache     271 Jan  8  2012 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    1369 Oct  3 07:47 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxrwx---.  1 eugene apache    3103 Dec 11 13:52 wp-config.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    2764 May  9  2015 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrws---.  5 eugene apache      63 Dec 11 10:36 wp-content
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxrws---. 16 eugene apache    8192 Dec  8 15:45 wp-includes
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    2380 Oct 24  2013 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    3316 Nov  5 15:59 wp-load.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache   33710 Nov  6 14:36 wp-login.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    7887 Oct  6 07:07 wp-mail.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache   13021 Nov 19 23:24 wp-settings.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache   28594 Oct 30 01:52 wp-signup.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    4035 Nov 30  2014 wp-trackback.php
-rwxrws---.  1 eugene apache    3061 Oct  2 15:46 xmlrpc.php
[eugene@myvps www]$ cd wp-content/
[eugene@myvps wp-content]$ ll
total 4
-rwxrws---. 1 eugene apache 28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxrws---. 3 eugene apache 52 Dec  8 15:45 plugins
drwxrws---. 5 eugene apache 83 Dec  8 15:45 themes
drwxrws---. 2 eugene apache  6 Dec 11 11:59 uploads
[eugene@myvps wp-content]$
```

I even went as far as giving `wp-content` 777, but still getting the same error. :(

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after banging my head on my desk and /face_through_desk. I figured it out.

SELinux to the rescue! Or not...

I ran into this article which goes over configuring SELinux for Wordpress uploads: [How to allow WordPress to upload images on an SELinux enabled server](http://blog.palehorse.net/2008/01/24/how-to-allow-wordpress-to-upload-images-on-an-selinux-enabled-server/)

Ultimately I ran:

```
chcon -t tmp_t uploads
```

And was able to keep my permissions as so... everything works now. Hope this can help someone else down the road. "CentOS was such a better idea vs Debian"